# How do you perform a filtered search with Rust's petgraph?

Tags: rust, petgraph

Rust's Petgraph library has a bunch of [filter 'adaptors'](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.5.1/petgraph/visit/index.html), but I haven't been able to find any examples or tutorials for how to use them. Some (but not all) have constructors, such as [EdgeFiltered.from_fn()](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.5.1/petgraph/visit/struct.EdgeFiltered.html#method.from_fn) which takes a graph and a function, but it's not clear how you'd then use it with the search methods like [Dfs](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.5.1/petgraph/visit/struct.Dfs.html) or [astar](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.5.1/petgraph/algo/fn.astar.html) as they don't have filter parameters.

So how do you use these filters? For example, if I had a graph with integer edge weights how would you:

1. Perform a depth first search but excluding edges with a negative weight,
2. Perform an astar search excluding edges with a negative weight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adapters implement `GraphBase`, you can just wrap your graph in them and pass the adapter struct to e.g. `Dfs`:

```
use petgraph::Graph;
use petgraph::visit::Dfs;
use petgraph::visit::EdgeFiltered;

fn main() {
    let mut graph = Graph::<(), i64>::new();
    let a = graph.add_node(());
    let b = graph.add_node(());
    let e = graph.add_edge(a, b, -1);
    let filtered = EdgeFiltered::from_fn(&graph, |edge_ref| *edge_ref.weight() > 0 );
    let dfs = Dfs::new(&filtered, a);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=86639bf94a85f0ee0914e617100336f5)

Comment: What about things like https://docs.rs/petgraph/latest/petgraph/visit/struct.NodeFilteredEdges.html# that doesn't have a `from_fn`?

Comment: I haven't used petgraph in a long time, but have you checked if https://docs.rs/petgraph/latest/petgraph/visit/struct.NodeFilteredEdges.html#impl-ElementIterator%3CN%2C%20E%3E `filter_elements()` provides what you need?